# attaching a child object to a parent object "error:Select either 1 or 3 vertices"

Tags: parent, 3d-cursor, origin, vertex-weights

[image: wanted to add]

I wanted to attach that red object to the lip of parent object.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGwyE1w8iZg&t=353s

I have followed this tutorial

Everything is good until 4:48 seconds, when he asked me to make a vertex the parent of the object.

When I did that, I get this error:

"Select either 1 or 3 vertices to parent to"

I don't know what exactly that error is and how to solve this.

Please can someone help regarding this, or if you know any better way to attach two objects on particular faces or location.

Please do let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is vertex parenting. It goes:

1. Select Child object(s)
2. Select Parent object
3. With Parent active, go into Edit Mode
4. Select either *exactly* 1 or *exactly* 3 vertices of the Parent mesh.
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> make the vertex, or vertices, the Parent of the child objects.

If 1 vertex, there is no inherited orientation. 3 is the minimum number of vertices to define an orientation to be inherited. At the moment, Blender does not want more. It does not yet seem to want to mess with averaged normals, or whatever it would take to make sense of 4 or more.

Comment: thats not working 
i selected exactly three verices or faces  and tried to use ctrl p 
but stil getting the same error
https://ibb.co/DQrq1VM
added image 
near nose added three vertices 
im sorry if im using any terms wrong im new to blender

Comment: Hi @John! I _think_ you've selected 3 faces, not 3 vertices. Hit Keyboard '1' in Edit Mode, to switch to Vertex Selection, and select 3 of those.

Comment: thank you so  much 
got sorted